# How to ask a question and correctly tell its logic in the following case?

Tags: logic, some-any

My question is about logic in English. (In my native language (it's Russian) the logical words used in this case may differ, I'm not sure.)

Available variants of the question are:

- How to list all branches that are not merged into **none** of the given branches?
- How to list all branches that are not merged into **any** of the given branches?
- (Maybe you'll propose a better wording.)

The logic is the following:

- I have a lot of branches: A, B, C, ..., Z.
- Any of them may be merged to any other.
- Some of them are special: I, J, K.
- For each branch I want the following:

  - if the branch is not merged into I **and** it is not merged into J **and** it is not merged into K
  - then I want to include this branch into the resulting list,
  - but if it is merged into any of I,J,K - then I don't want this branch.

How do I pose my question in English correctly in this case?

N.B. The question is from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62653225/how-to-list-git-branches-not-merged-to-given-branches

P. S. It seems to me that "not merged into **any**" seems like "if it is not merged into I **or** not merged into J **or** not merged into K then I want this branch". Am I right?

UPD.

1. "(not merged) into (any)" =
   "(not merged) into (J or K)" =
   "(not merged into J) **or** (not merged into K)"
2. but
   "not (merged into any)" =
   "not (merged into (J or K)" =
   "not ((merged into J) or (merged into K))" =
   "(not merged into J) **and** (not merged into K)"
   (according to [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws))

- notice the difference in resulting operator: or vs and

Comment: *Not merged into none* is a double negative that has almost the opposite meaning of *not merged into any*, so it can't be both of those …

Comment: *List all branches that do not eventually merge into another branch.*

Comment: @JasonBassford It seems to me that "not merged into any" seems like "if it is not merged into I **or** not merged into J **or** not merged into K then I want this branch". Am I right?

Comment: You seem to have used *any* in the last line of your logic. Does that answer the question? But you don't actually need *any* or *none:* you want a branch which is not merged into I or J or K.

Comment: @whyer *Not merged into any* means *not merged into I **and** not merged into J **and** not merged into K.* If you use *not* and *or*, then it **could** be merged into any of them, but just not *all* of them …

Comment: The normal English way of saying it would be: "How to list all branches that ***are*** merged into ***none*** of the given branches."  Of course using set notation would make the whole thing completely unambiguous.

Comment: @AndrewLeach the problem here is: "(not merged) into (any)" = "(not merged) into (J or K)" = "(not merged into J) or (not merged into K)"
but
"not (merged into any)" = "not (merged into (J or K)" = "not ((merged into J) or (merged into K))" = "(not merged into J) and (not merged into K)"
(according to De Morgan's law)

Comment: @whyer That ought to go into the question. However, I believe I (and Jason) have explained what works in English.

Comment: @AndrewLeach and I'm not allowed to mention I,J,K in my question (because the list of special branches is not known at the time of asking the question) - therefore I call them "given branches"

Comment: @AndrewLeach yes you explained, if I understood correctly, "not merged into any" means "not merged into J **and** not merged into K" and not "not merged into J **or** not merged into K" in English. But unfortunately I still don't get what should be the correct posing then

Comment: @chaslyfromUK maybe this variant ("that are merged into none of given branches") should be an answer, not a comment? looks like it answers the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How my English works:

1. Not merged into any of {I, J, K} = "Not merged into I or J or K" but you can simply say "Not merged into any of the given branches"

   None of the given branches have the branch in question merged into them.

   You can parse this as "Not merged into I *and* not merged into J *and* not merged into K." The *and* becomes *or* when "not merged into" is applied to all the alternatives together.
2. You can choose to parse that differently, "Not (merged into any of {I, J, K})" but it means exactly the same thing. Your branch **could** go into any of {I, J, K}, but it hasn't.
3. Merged into none of {I, J, K} : same again. None of {I, J, K} contains your branch.
4. Merged into any of {I, J, K} : this one doesn't say which your branch has been merged into. It could be I or J or K, or any two of them, or even all three. A "normal" layman's reading might suppose only one, but it doesn't have to be.
5. "Not merged into I and J and K" doesn't make a great deal of sense (see 1 about how *and* becomes *or*).

Comment: items #1 and 2 aren't different. __here is__ what is "parse it differently":
`Not (merged into any of {I, J, K})` vs 
`(Not merged) into any of {I, J, K})`
- and these two means the opposite, hence my confusion, since parentheses are not used in English like in math :)

Comment: fyi. donno if you know that, (maybe you'll find the following interesting) : "how _and_ becomes _or_" is called the laws of De Morgan https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 1):

Despite the question mark, neither of the examples

> *1. How to list all branches that are not merged into none of the given branches? / >2. How to list all branches that are not merged into any of the given branches?*

are questions.

The questions would be

*1. How **do you** list all branches that are not merged into none of the given branches?*

*2. How **do you** list **the** branches that are not merged into any of the given branches?*

Of these, only 2. is now correct but can be improved.

1. has a double negative but it can be corrected and improved:

*1. How **do you** list **the** branches that are merged into none of the given branches?*

Comment: could you pls explain why a question starting with 'how to' isn't a question? and why did you replace "**all** branches that are" with "**the** branches that are"?

Comment: You could say, for example, "Demonstrate how to list all branches ..." or simply "List all branches ...", or "Give a method for listing ...."

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Yes but they are not questions either - they are imperatives.

Comment: @whyer This is very basic English: Questions typically have an inverted verb/subject. **Statement 1** "I (subject) fly (verb) a plane (object). **Question 1** "Do (active verb) I (subject) fly(infinitive) a plane (object)?  **Statement 2** "How beautiful you look." **Question 2** "How do you look beautiful?"  **All** is unnecessary - all the branches are already defined by the defining relative clause.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of [DeMorgan's Laws](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/Logicguide.pdf):

- `¬(p ⋀ q) ≣ (¬p ⋁ ¬q)` In English, "not (p **and** q) is equivalent to (not p **or** not q)"
- `¬(p ⋁ q) ≣ (¬p ⋀ ¬q)` In English, "not (p **or** q) is equivalent to (not p **and** not q)"

In other words, the logical functors `OR` and `AND` reverse under negation, much like positive and negative numbers when multiplying by -1. This happens also in English syntax.

- *If it's not in A, B, **or** C, then it's not in A, (**and**) it's not in B, **and** it's not in C.*
- *If it's not in A, B, **and** C, then (**either**) it's not in A, (**or**) it's not in B, **or** it's not in C.*

Such equivalences work best between two variables. With three or more, as in the example above, conjunction reduction makes ambiguity more possible. Of course, since writing doesn't include intonation or stress, every written sentence is multiply ambiguous, so saying it in English isn't much of a solution.

Comment: does "it's not in A or B" mean "it's (not in) (A or B)" or "it's not (in (A or B)"? is the `not`, `or` and `any` operators precedence assumed in English? (because `(not in) (A or B)` means completely different than `not (in (A or B))`!)

Comment: There is no "any" operator. _Any_ is an English word and a negative polarity item; it's not logic, it's syntax. And _it's not in A or B_ is an English clause, not a logical formula. The parentheses in English examples indicate optional words, not logical groupings.